# How to test Apex queueable is stopped with given condition?

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage, queueable-apex

Here is my queueable, which stops at the beginning when condition is set.

It seems that the initiated queueable instance in Test is gone after `Test.stopTest()`?
The test execution error is `Expected: true, Actual: null`

**Queueable**

```
public class queuer implements Queueable {
  @TestVisible
  private Boolean isStopped;

  public void execute(QueueableContext context) {
    if (isStopped()) {
      return;
    }

    System.debug('code after stopped check');
  }

  private Boolean isStopped() {
    isStopped = true;
    System.debug('this.isStopped: ' + isStopped);

    return isStopped;
  }
}
```

**Test Class**

```
@IsTest
public with sharing class QueuerTest {
  @IsTest
  public static void it_stops() {
    Queuer q = new Queuer();

    Test.startTest();
    System.enqueueJob(q);
    Test.stopTest();

    System.assertEquals(
      true,
      q.isStopped,
      'queueable should be stopped.'
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't test for the stopped but assert that the insert/update (whatever would happen otherwise) didn't.

Comment: @Girbot your thought is reasonable. I'd like to separate the qeueable functionality test from business logic test whenever possible.

Comment: Queueable job is serialized at moment of execution, and then it is not being changed in the context of method where it was executed originally. Therefore you can not get the updated state of it (in unit tests as well). An advice would be to either check it on database level, or execute logic from queueable job manually

Answer (score 0):

one of my colleagues gives a reasonably good solution.
Use a static Boolean property in the queueable class. it can be read after `Test.stopTest()`.

IMO It's better than relying on DMLs.